# How can I convert JSON object to readable swift object?

Tags: json, swift, socket.io

This is the JSON data I receive from the server:

```
[{
    "_id": someRandomID;
    comment = {
        identifier = someRandomIdentifier;
        text = someRandomText;
    };
}]
```

I am using `socket.io` and I get the data from `socket.on()` as below:

```
socket?.on("add-comment") {data, ack in
   print(data)
}
```

I have tried to create a class for it as below:

```
class addComment: Codable {
let _id: String
let comment: comments
}

class comments: Codable {
    let identifier: String
    let text: String

    init(identifier: String, text: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

and inside socket.on I added the following codes:

```
socket?.on("add-comment") {data, ack in
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let comment = decoder.decode(addComment.self, from: data)
}
```

It shows me the following:

> cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'

Can anyone please guide through how can I convert the data object I receive from the server to a readable object in swift to be able to access its values?

Comment: Did you try to cast?

Comment: @Yitzchak yes, it didn't work as well

Comment: On which line do you see the error?

Comment: @Yitzchak this line, "let comment = decoder.decode(addComment.self, from: data)"

Comment: let comment = decoder.decode(addComment.self, from: data as! Data)

Comment: The error message says that the `data` parameter is an Array of type `Any` rather than an expected `Data` instance. The compiler is as clueless as we are about the actual type in the array.

Comment: let comment = decoder.decode(addComment.self, from: data[0] as! Data)

Comment: @Yitzchak It shows me an error "Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' to 'NSData'

Comment: Is it Runtime error? or compile time? What is Data? is it your class? or you think it's swift's Data class (that corresponds to NSData in ObjC)

Comment: [This article](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999) can help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this array in the completion handler, `data` is **not** of type `Data`

```
let data : [Any]  = [["_id": "someRandomID", 
                      "comment" : ["identifier" : "someRandomIdentifier", 
                                   "text" : "someRandomText"]
                                  ]
                    ]
```

To use `Codable` you need to serialize the array to JSON

These are your classes conforming to the Swift naming convention

```
class AddComment: Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id", comment
    }

    let id: String
    let comment: Comment
}

class Comment: Codable {
    let identifier: String
    let text: String
}
```

And this is the way to make the array `Codable` compliant

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let addComments = try decoder.decode([AddComment].self, from: jsonData)
    print(addComments[0])

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: it shows me that "AddComment" class has no initializers. I tried to add init() function but then it shows me that the class doesn't confront to decodable

Comment: If `AddComment` conforms to `Codable` it has (implicit) initializers. But actually you don't need classes. Replace `class` with `struct`. Copy&paste my entire code in a Playground to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Add square brackets around the object you want to create, your json is an array of (1) objects, not an object.

try this:

```
let comments = decoder.decode([addComment].self, from: data)
```

(also your class name as a plural without a starting capital is quite confusing)

Comment: The comments reveal clearly that `data` does not contain any `Data` not even `[Data]`

Comment: He said he 'received JSON-data from the server'. So I assumed data was already in JSON format. Either way he'll need to add the square brackets though

Comment: He said also that he *Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' to 'NSData*, so logically `data` is an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

More generic way ...

```
class SocketParser {

    static func convert<T: Decodable>(data: Any) throws -> T {
        var result : T?
        
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            result = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
            
        }catch{
            createLog("CheckError \(error)")
        }
        return result!
    }
    

}
```

then use like follow ... on socket responce

```
   guard let dataInfo = data.first else{
      return
    }

  
  if let response : [AddComment] = try? SocketParser.convert(data: dataInfo)  {
           print(responce) 
     }
```